# How to hold all comments for moderation, including author's comments on own post

Tags: comments

I want all comments no matter what, to be held for moderation and not appear till approved by an admin. Wordpress allows author comments on own posts to show up without holding for moderation. Any way around that please?

Answer (score 0):

In the WordPress Admin Dashboard:

1. Click on the Settings menu item.
2. Click on the Discussion sub menu item.
3. Remove the check in the box next to *Comment author must have a previously approved comment*.
4. Click the Save Changes button.

Comment: I tried that, not working. When someone comments on his own post, it shows up instantly without any moderation.